# non resourceful routes with model attributes and url helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a problem with the helpers url and path helpers for a non-resourceful route,

There is a model `Item` that has, among other attributes, an `sku` attribute

so the default routing with

```
resources :items
```

creates the default index route

```
item GET        /items/:id(.:format)                              items#show
```

But I want to override that route to match urls like:

```
/sku/:sku/id/:id
```

instead of the default urls:

```
/items/:id
```

So I created the following route and put it above `resources :items` to be matched first:

```
get "sku/:sku/id/:id" => "items#show", as: "item"
```

and it works correctly if I go to `www.example.com/sku/2342/id/8484` it shows me the correct Item.

However, my problem is if I want to use the `item_path` or `item_url` helpers passing the object to them.

Instead of getting the desired path `/sku/2342/id/8484` I am getting a path with the id of the item applied twice like `/sku/8484/id/8484`

I searched in google and here in StackOverflow for several minutes and I cant find the answer, I already read the Rails routing documentation but still no success, hope some one can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing something like `item_path(item, item)`. I'm not sure that will work. If you pass in the actual object, it grabs the `id` field.

Did you try `item_path(item.sku, item)`?

Comment: hey, thanks! using item_url(@item.sku, @item) worked, now I get the URL that I wanted